# wp-bootstrap-navwalker breakpoint change

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I am currently using this as part of my wordpress theme for mobile navigation.

Is there a way to change at which size the dropdown navigation appears?

I looked in wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php but couldn't see where this was set?

I Want this to be shown instead of the normal navigation when the normal navigation rolls onto 2 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The breakpoint itself is baked into Bootstrap 3, not wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php. You can update the breakpoints your self at the following URL:

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints

Or override them in your bootstrap.css file.

Comment: Thank you, I have done it in my style.css, to show the dropdown nav. Im just confused as to how i can hide my current navigation and use the dropdown, as the dropdown uses the current one

Comment: Ok, if this solves your query, please accept the answer. Can you be clearer on the new problem you are solving?